# SQL ExecuteReader throws "Incorrect syntax near GO"

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I use a T-SQL command which I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) to get the fragmentation of my database tables. When I execute the T-SQL in the Management Studio, everything works. If I use it inside PowerShell, I get the following error (translated from German):

```
Exception when calling "ExecuteReader" with 0 Argument(s): 
"Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."
In Zeile:17 Zeichen:6
+      $Result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

This is the part of my script which throws the error

```
foreach ($table in $tables)
{
     $Data = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
     $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
     $getFragRate = "
     -- SQL Command von Microsoft um die Index Fragmentation zu überprüfen 
     USE Logik;  
     GO  
     SELECT a.index_id, name, avg_fragmentation_in_percent  
     FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'Logik'), OBJECT_ID(N'$($table)'), NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a  
         JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id;   
     GO  
     "
     $cmd.CommandText = $getFragRate 
     $cmd.Connection = $con
     $Result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
     $Data.Load($Result)
     $Data
}
```

Why does this error occur?

The User I use to do this has `sysadmin`, `db_ddladmin` and `db_owner` permission.

Edit: Another T-SQL Command to get all tables of my database worked without a problem from PowerShell.

Comment: `GO` is **NOT** a T-SQL command - therefore you cannot have it in T-SQL statements being executed from PowerShell. `GO` is a **batch separator** used by SQL Server Management Studio. You need to break up that statement into several individual statements yourself and execute them one by one

Comment: Further to @marc_s answer, you don't actually need either of the GO statements in that code. A USE statement can happily be followed directly by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GO` is *NOT* a T-SQL command - therefore you cannot have it in T-SQL statements being executed from PowerShell.

`GO` is a batch separator used by SQL Server Management Studio.

You need to break up that statement into several individual statements yourself and execute them one by one.